# Nunit TestResult.xml is not created during Jenkins build

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, nunit

**To run tests in Jenkins I use the next batch command:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" /result:TestResult.xml "C:\Users\Denis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\App.nunit"
```

**Here how it looks in Jenkis:**

[image: Jenkis screen]

**The problem is:** it doesn't generate `TestResult.xml` file!

When I run the same command as a `.bat` file from my desctop it creates the `TestResult.xml` file.

**Any ideas what is wrong with Jenkins?**

**P.S.** I searched for created file in all possible folders and even via "search"

Comment: Well I just read the command line options page for your pogram and I do not see a **/result** option.  The program by default will output the file TestResult.xml file in the working directory from where you launched the command.  http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5

Comment: Look here) http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with thought that the file is generated and removed then or something like this.

The thing is that I don't see this file indeed but Jenkins generated report based on this file! So I think maybe after generating report the file was removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and I found the test results xml file under my user directory in Win 7. 
Note : I think it's some problem with nunit that it doesn't export the file to the location of which we provide the path.